# cellForRowAtIndexPath not called after reloadData but numberOfRowsInSection does

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my current project I'm trying to fetch news from a REST-Endpoint and I wanna refresh the `UITableView` once the network request is finished. So I call `reloadData()` but unfortunately `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't called however `numberOfRowsInSection` gets called and returns the correct number of items.

Following my code stripped down to the relevant parts:

```
class NewsTableViewController: UIViewController {

    private var newsItems: Array<NewsItem>!
    private var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newsItems = []
        addDummyItem()
        prepareTableView()
        getNews()
    }

    func addDummyItem(){
        let newsItem = NewsItem()
        newsItem.dateString = "12th May"
        newsItem.title = "Lorem ipsum"
        newsItem.imgUrl = "URL"
        newsItem.url = "URL"
        newsItem.message = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        self.newsItems.append(newsItem)
    }

    func getNews(){
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://someurl.com/news")
        let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) { data, response, error in
            guard data != nil && error == nil else {
                print(error)
                return
            }

            guard let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                print("status code not 200; \(response)")
                return
            }
            let json = String(data:data!, encoding: NSISOLatin1StringEncoding)
            let arr: AnyObject? = json?.parseJSONString
            for item in arr as! Array<AnyObject>{
                let newsItem = NewsItem()
                newsItem.dateString = (item["dateString"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? ""
                newsItem.title = (item["title"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? ""
                newsItem.imgUrl = (item["imgUrl"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? ""
                newsItem.url = (item["url"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? ""
                newsItem.message = (item["message"] as AnyObject? as? String) ?? ""
                self.newsItems.append(newsItem)
            }
            print("Network request finished - call reloadData()")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
               self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    }

    private func prepareTableView() {
        tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
}

extension NewsTableViewController : UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Item count: ", newsItems.count)
        return newsItems.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cellForRowAtIndexPath called with indexPathRow: ", indexPath.row)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageCardViewCell") as! NewsImageCardViewCell
        let item: NewsItem = newsItems[indexPath.row]
        getImageCardView(item.url, btnDate: item.dateString, textTitle: item.title, textDetail: item.message, imageCardView: cell.imageCardView, imageName: "news_1", indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

extension NewsTableViewController : UITableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

As you can see: The `UITableView` is correctly setup by setting the `dataSource` and `delegate` to my class. The `reloadData()` method is called on the main thread. Following the log-output:

```
Item count:  1
cellForRowAtIndexPath called with indexPathRow:  0
Network request finished - call reloadData()
Item count:  72
```

**Note:** At first there's one dummy item my array just to show you that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is indeed called but only one time. After triggering `reloadData()` on `numberOfRowsInSection` is called but not the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

I know that there're a lot of similar issues like this and I've checked them all for possible solutions but none were working. I appreciate any help.

### Edit

Please note that the dummy view which is added before the network request is visible. So the `UITableView`s' height is not 0.

### Edit #2

Thanks to everyone for your answers. I've found the issue. I've instantiated the `ViewController` via the `Storyboard` but I missed to set an `IBOutlet`. Due that the bounds of my `UITableView` were 0,0,0,0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That because your table view did not add to your window, If the table view is not visible, the UIKit will not deal with UI related methods. It's kind of Apple's `lazy load`.
Change your `prepareTableView` function as below:

```
private func prepareTableView() {
    tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .Plain)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

Comment: The UITableView is visible otherwise the first view (the dummy view which gets added before the network request) won't be visible. I'll add this to my question just for clarification.

Comment: Your should let your table view has a no nil superview.

Comment: You can make it invisible, but it should add to it's super view.

Comment: @user3420815 I think zylenv's answer is correct because you are not adding your tableview to to self.view then how its possible you can see your table view. Do you have UITableviewObject in storyBorad or Nib so its displaying ?

Comment: @Pandey_Laxman That's it. I've totally missed that I instantiate the VC via the Storyboard.

Comment: Okay glad to hear that you got solution , make sure you have tablview Delegate and datasource set to view in StoryBoard if you are using that Also dont forget mark zylenv as accepted and upvote my comment.

Answer (score 6):

Check Following :

1 `numberOfRowsInSection` see the Number of return value

2 if step1 is called and return right value still not calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` that means your table view height is less then height of cell or table view height is 0 , print tableview bounds and also check superview of tableview has clips to bounds to TRUE

Comment: The dummy view/row which I do add before the network request is visible so the height can't be 0.

Comment: print bounds of tableview

Comment: `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` which is kinda strange considering the fact that the first row is shown?

Comment: as i mentioned if your table is 0 height i twill not call cell for row

Comment: @user3420815 if this answer helps then mark is correct so other can also help

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: just set height of your table view with either autolayout or frame however you are adding tableview , see superview of tableview bounds.

Answer (score 0):

tableview datasource method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is depending on `numberOfRowsInSection` . So it may be possiblity that you having zero item in `newsItems`

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not in `delegate` , it comes under in `dataSource`

Comment: This is a valid answer, why to vote it negative, just because he typed delegate

Comment: @gunjotsingh - i m not given negative Vote

Comment: yes he mentioned, he is getting count 72, but he needs to double check it. Because if newsItems having data then cellForRowAtIndexPath must be called. In my answer I have clearly mentioned it may be possiblity that you having zero item in newsItems